# Можно ли в sql получить результат который не найден?

Tags: mysql, myisam

Можно ли в sql получить результат который не найден?

```
SELECT name FROM `names` WHERE name IN ('vasya','json','liza','vladimir','andrey');
```

возвращает:

```
vasya
liza
```

а как сделать, чтобы возвращало:

```
json
vladimir
andrey
```

?

Работает так:

```
WITH vals (Name) AS (VALUES ('vasya'),('json'),('liza'),('vladimir'),('andrey')))
SELECT Name FROM  vals
WHERE Name NOT IN (
  SELECT * 
  FROM `Names`
  WHERE Name IN (SELECT * FROM vals)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Для того, что вывести результат, обратный найденному, используется отрицание **NOT**

```
SELECT name 
FROM `names` 
WHERE name NOT IN ('vasya','json','liza','vladimir','andrey');
```

И теперь запрос читается, как, *Выведи значения поля name, где name не содержит следующие значения*

Answer (score 1):

Самый оптимальный вариант, наверное, был бы с использованием временной таблицы. Создать ее, сохранить туда эти имена как константы.

```
CREATE TABLE temp_names (`name` varchar(16));
INSERT INTO temp_names VALUES ('vasya'), ('json'), ('liza'), ('vladimir'), ('andrey');
```

и дальше уже использовать вложенные запросы:

```
  SELECT `name` 
  FROM `temp_names` 
  WHERE `name` NOT IN (
    SELECT `name` FROM `names` WHERE name IN (
      SELECT `name` FROM `temp_names`
    )
  )
```

Вот пример: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1161d4/3

Хотя в общем-то можно написать и короче.

```
  SELECT `name` 
  FROM `temp_names` 
  WHERE `name` NOT IN (
    SELECT `name` FROM `names`
  )
```

Но на больших таблицах может работать медленей первого варианта.

Если временные таблицы не подходят, то можно попробовать вариант создания такой таблицы прямо в запросе.

```
SELECT `name` FROM 
(SELECT 'vasya' AS `name` 
     UNION SELECT 'json' AS `name` 
     UNION SELECT 'liza' AS `name`
     UNION SELECT 'vladimir' AS `name`
     UNION SELECT 'andrey' AS `name`
) AS t 
   WHERE `name` NOT IN (
     SELECT `name` FROM `names`
   );
```

Это вариация предыдущего варианта, только константы берутся не из временной таблицы, а формируются в запросе.

Пример: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04613b/4